# Using `find` on not existing directory

Tags: shell, find

Is there a simple way to make this silently do nothing, if `/my-directory` does not exist?

```
find /my-directory -type f -mtime +14 -print0 | xargs -r0 rm
```

Versions:

- find: GNU findutils 4.5.10
- bash 4.2.53

Answer (score 15):

You can throw away error reporting from `find` with `2>/dev/null`, or you can avoid running the command at all:

```
test -d /my-directory && find /my-directory -type f -mtime +14 -print0 | xargs -r0 rm
```

As a slight optimisation and clearer code, some versions of `find` - including yours - can perform the `rm` for you directly:

```
test -d /my/directory && find /my-directory -type f -mtime +14 -delete
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use,

```
find /my-directory -type f -mtime +14 -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -r0 rm
```

**Explaination:**

`2> /dev/null` means redirects stderr to `/dev/null`.

- `/dev/null` is the null device it takes any input you want and throws it away. It can be used to suppress any output.

Answer (score 2):

`print0` and `xargs -r 0` are useless here, `find` has that capability builtin:

```
[ -d /my-directory ] && find /my-directory -type f -mtime +14 -exec rm {} +
```

or, as you are using GNU find, this variant suggested by @terdon:

```
[ -d /my-directory ] && find /my-directory -type f -mtime +14 -delete
```

Comment: Since the OP is using GNU `find`, you could also just do `[ -d /my-directory ] && find /my-directory -type f -mtime +14 -delete`

Comment: @terdon You are right. I usually prefer to stick with POSIX syntax and avoid suggesting GNUisms when they have no (or very little) added value though.